# HTML cannot see Javascript code; execution in php code breaks without error?

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv

I'm trying to execute some PHP code, and then afterward use Javascript to take one of my PHP variables and use it to open a new window with that variable's contents on it in CSV format.

This works when my PHP variable is relatively small (i.e. 1,000 entries), but when I execute it on code that has for example about 20,000 entries in the array, it stops in the PHP code below without throwing any errors. What could be my issue? Yesterday I traced the issue to array_column - that the code would simply stop executing once it got to that line. However, it did it again today, even without that function and I gathered that there must be a bigger issue. I've re-included those array_column() calls since I assume they're not the real problem. Here's the PHP code:

```
function generateTextFile(){
    $array = $_SESSION["array"];
    $hostCol = array_column($array, "host");
    $timeCol = array_column($array, "Time");
    $col3 = array_column($array, "col3");
    $col4 = array_column($array, "col4");
    $signalCol = array_column($array, "Signal");

    for($x = 0; $x < count($timeCol); $x++){
        if(!isset($array[$x]["host"])){
            $hostCol[$x] = $_GET['hostname'];
        }
        else{
            $hostCol[$x] = $array[$x]["host"];
        }
    }
    $subArray = array($hostCol, $timeCol, $col3, $col4, $signalCol);

    $out = array();
    foreach($subArray as $rowkey => $row){ // invert the array
        foreach($row as $colkey => $col)
            $out[$colkey][$rowkey] = $col;
    }

    $text = "";
    for($x = 0; $x < count($out); $x++){
        $curText = implode(",", $out[$x]);
        $text = $text . $curText . "<br>";
    }
    $_SESSION['text'] = $text;
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong in the above PHP code? It just builds an array and then makes another variable in CSV format. I declared the script in the  section of my HTML, after the above function is called. I'd be very grateful for your insight.

Comment: What's your php's `max_execution_time`? If it works with few records but breaks with many it could be a timeout issue. Try to [increase time limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and test if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP have the thing called "time limit" to proccess the scripts.
The default is 30 seconds, and you can change this:

```
set_time_limit( int $seconds );
```

I had the same issue trying to proccess about 6.000 CSV's, and solved with this method.
Hope you find this useful!